# AssemblyVersionAttribute not found by Assembly.GetCustomAttributesData

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes, .net-assembly

You can load an Assembly and query all assembly attributes, including `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`, `AssemblyVersionAttribute` and `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`. But when opening the assembly for reflection only with the `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` method, only the informational version and file version are listed, not the `AssemblyVersionAttribute`.

Why don't I get that attribute as well?

Mono Cecil can read them all, as ILSpy demonstrates. But that library is too bulky for my specific tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the compiler and runtime *both lie*. [Just like The Doctor](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Doctor#The_Doctor.27s_Rules).

There are some attributes that do **not** actually get embedded in their natural form. `AssemblyVersionAttribute` is one of them. Another is `SerializableAttribute`. They do *not* get added as `.custom instance` entries, but are represented via other information.

Now, for the *regular* reflection model, the runtime can spoof over this - making it appear like it had actually added them as attribute metadata - by pulling the values out of where it *actually* goes, and pretending. It does not do this for reflection-only models.

You'll just need to check the assembly version via the assembly instance instead. In IL terms, this is the `.ver` in the `.assembly` entry. But `assembly.GetName().Version` is probably the easiest way to read it at runtime.

You can verify this by looking at the raw assembly in reflector, ildasm, or any other tool of choice.

Comment: Would this have any correlation to CodeAnalysis reporting the missing AssemblyVersionAttribute (although I can clearly see it in the AssemblyInfo.cs)?